# React Password generator

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a React novice (decent in basic javascript) and I've created a simply password generator widget and well, I cant seem to get it working like I want. I started with 2 separate widgets (1 - to make sure I could display the  randomize password and 2 - to see if I could get radio buttons and simple error checking implemented), but now that I've merged them together, the password's wont display. 
Can someone help me figure out where I've went wrong? Any suggestions to improve the code are greatly appreciated as well (This isnt the final version, its more a proof of concept.

codepen is here: https://codepen.io/RCP1990/pen/Zogbwa?editors=0110

My Babel is

```
class AppPicker extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      appl:'',
      message:'Please select an application',
      pass:'[Password]',
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      appl: event.target.value
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const chosen = this.state.appl;
    if (chosen == ''){
      this.setState({ message:'You didnt select an application!' })
    }

    else if (chosen != '') { 
      const obj = [ "Amaze", "Apple", 
          "Bacon", "Beach", "Beer","Bench","Bill", "Blue", "Books", "Bounce", "Bubble","Bunny",
          "Cake","Candy","Canoe", "Cat", "Chirpy","Cherry", "Clouds", "Cream", "Comet",
          "Dan","Dance","Dream","Dtown","Dog", 
          "Flan", "Flip", "Flower", "Fluff","Funny",
          "Glad", "Goose","Green", 
          "Happy","Hello","Hodor", "Hugs",
          "Jaunty", "Jolly", "Jump", 
          "Karate", "Kayak", "Kitten","Kitty", 
          "Lager", "Latte", "Laugh", "Lift","Lilly", "Lion","Light", "Loved", 
          "Merry","Mocha", "Morty", "Music", 
          "Nature",
          "Ocean", 
          "Peppy","Plant","Play", "Pretty","Puppy", "Pop", "Pony", "Pork", 
          "Quick", 
          "Red","Rick", "Rose", "Rosy", "Roses", "Run", 
          "Shark", "Shine", "Skip", "Sleep", "Smile","Sport","Star", "Sweet",
          "Tech","Tiger", "Trees", "Triple", "Turtle",  
          "Walk", "Water",  "Widly",  
          "Zen", "Zippy","Zombie", ];

         if (chosen =='Fannie Mae') {
          const symbol = ["@", "-", "_"];
         }
         else {
           const symbol = ["@", "#", "$"];
         }

         var initPass = obj[Math.floor(Math.random()*obj.length)];
         var initSym = symbol[Math.floor(Math.random()*symbol.length)];   

         this.setState({ pass: initPass+initSym })
     }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <h3>Password Generator</h3>
        <p className="warning">{this.state.message}</p>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <label>
              <input
                type="radio"
                value="MSP"
                checked={this.state.appl === "MSP"}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
              MSP
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label>
              <input
                type="radio"
                value="Fannie Mae"
                checked={this.state.appl === "Fannie Mae"}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
              Fannie Mae
            </label>
          </li>
          <li>
            <label>
              <input
                type="radio"
                value="LivePerson"
                checked={this.state.appl === "LivePerson"}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              />
              LivePerson
            </label>
          </li>
      </ul>
        <div>{this.state.pass}</div>
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-lg">Generate</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<AppPicker />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually your code has an error, here exactly:

```
        if (chosen =='Fannie Mae') {
          const symbol = ["@", "-", "_"]; //here
         }
         else {
           const symbol = ["@", "#", "$"]; // and here
         }

         var initPass = obj[Math.floor(Math.random()*obj.length)];
         var initSym = symbol[Math.floor(Math.random()*symbol.length)]; //and here
```

the main problem is that you are defining `symbol` two times and it is not defined when your case is `MSP`.

also for the block of code of the IF/ELSE your variable wont exist outside of it. so when you do `symbol.length` it wont be defined. the correct way of your code would be to initialize the variable symbol and then assign it based on each case. like this:

```
        let symbol = [];
        if (chosen =='Fannie Mae') {
          symbol = ["@", "-", "_"];
         }
         else {
           symbol = ["@", "#", "$"];
         }

         var initPass = obj[Math.floor(Math.random()*obj.length)];
         var initSym = symbol[Math.floor(Math.random()*symbol.length)]; //and then this will work.
```

Answer (score 1):

It's this block:

```
if (chosen =='Fannie Mae') {
  const symbol = ["@", "-", "_"];
}
else {
  const symbol = ["@", "#", "$"];
}
```

You're declaring const symbol within a limited scope. After leaving the if block, symbol is lost. You need to move symbol above the if, and replace the const modifier with a let, since you won't be able to set it after initial declaration

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working version:
https://codepen.io/leogoesger/pen/jKBeBG?editors=0011

What you had:

```
if (chosen =='Fannie Mae') {
          const symbol = ["@", "-", "_"];
         }
         else {
           const symbol = ["@", "#", "$"];
         }
```

What you should have done:

```
    let symbol;
    if (chosen =='Fannie Mae') {
       symbol = ["@", "-", "_"];
    }
    else {
       symbol = ["@", "#", "$"];
    }
```

This is really a simple error with Javascript. Next time, I would recommend try to solve it with the debugger, instead of asking it here.

Comment: Son of a gun, we answered at the exact same second

Comment: I was going to post code, but then I saw you guys answer. High fives all around.

Answer (score 1):

Read up on block scope in ES6. First, it's a bad idea to define variables in if/else blocks. But with ES6, `const` and `let` get block scoped to the block they were created in. Previously, you only had functional or global scope. Since you define `symbol` in the if/else blocks, they aren't accessible outside of those blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `symbol` is the issue. You are declaring it in the if/else condition.

Try changing this:

```
 if (chosen =='Fannie Mae') {
   const symbol = ["@", "-", "_"];
 }
 else {
  symbol = ["@", "#", "$"];
 }
```

to:

```
let symbol = ["@", "#", "$"];
if (chosen =='Fannie Mae') {
  symbol = ["@", "-", "_"];
}
```

...because symbol can't be recognized on the line where you set `initSym`